# Angular6 Material Dialog prevent from closing when pressing enter

Tags: dialog, angular6, angular-material-6

I have a login dialog and want to prevent it from closing automatically when enter is pressed.

To be more specific, when the user put the credential and pressed enter and the response for credential came back as error, I want the dialog to stay (so I can show them some error message and let the user try once again).

So this is what I did:

```
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginComponent>) { }

    onSubmit(): void {  
        this.authService.login(...)
            .subscribe(res => { 
                ... 
             },
            error => {
                this.dialogRef.disableClose = true;
            }
    }
}
```

`this.dialogRef.disableClose = true;` still closes the dialog even though the response came back as error.

How should I do this?

**Edit**

login.component.ts

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <span>Login</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-card class="my-card">
    <div *ngIf="error" style="color: red;">{{error}}</div><br />
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="loginForm">     
        <mat-card-content>       
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="full-width">
                <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Email" 
                   formControlName="email" 
                   [formControl]="emailFormControl" 
                   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
                <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
                    Enter valid email address
                </mat-error>   
                <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
                    Required field
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="full-width">
                <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="password" 
                   placeholder="Password" 
                   formControlName="password" 
                   [formControl]="passwordFormControl" 
                   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" />
                <mat-error *ngIf="passwordFormControl.hasError('required')">
                    Required field
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>                
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="onNoClick()" color="primary">Close</button>
            <button mat-raised-button 
                [disabled]="!(loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.password.valid)" 
                color="accent">
                Login
            </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

login.component.ts

```
onSubmit(): void {       
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }             
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.controls.email.value, this.loginForm.controls.password.value)
        .subscribe(res => {               
            if (res) {
                alert("logged in");              
            }   
        },
        error => {                  
            this.error = 'Error! Plese try again.'; 
        }
    );       
}
```

Comment: MatDialog does not by default close when the user presses the enter key. It has to be deliberately closed using the close() function. Somewhere in your code you are closing it. Is it possible that the initial focus is on your cancel/close button? Share all of your code.

Comment: You are right. initial focus was on the close button. I switched the order of two buttons (close and login) and it works fine. I guess this is the easiest way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Button order is specified by material design guidelines so you should always follow those rules (affirmative action on the right). MatDialogConfig autoFocus=false lets you have nothing focussed initially so that might be a better option in your case.

Comment: Before `autoFocus=false` when I press enter it would close the dialog. After I applied it, it would not close it when I pressed enter initially, but if I typed some inputs and pressed enter, it would still close the dialog even though response came back as error.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are closing it before you have verified that the input is valid or before the response has been received.

Comment: I added my `onSubmit()` function. When it came back as error as you can see, I'm not closing the dialog. I guess I need something like `dialogClose = false` inside the error bracket.

Comment: Take an inventory of everywhere you are calling dialog.close() and trace back to how/when those functions are triggered - that should reveal the problem (this is not a technical issue it is a design issue). Otherwise, please post a complete working example on StackBlitz.

Comment: I tried to mimic it as much as possible. Please take a look at this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aby7mt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Comment: The enter key event `(keydown.enter)` needs to be handled by the inputs - use Event.preventDefault() to stop the event from automatically being passed to the first button.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe it's because your "CLOSE" button, is not set to type="button", and I THINK that's the first element that has focus, so when pressing enter, you are entering that button, which by default, will submit the form. Add type="button" and that should solve it.

Also for the record, the latest version of angular material has md-button automatically add type="button" by default (unless you specify type="submit") to avoid this type of situation

Use this

```
 <mat-card-actions>
        <button  mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="onNoClick()" color="primary">Close</button>
        <button  mat-raised-button type="submit" 
            [disabled]="!(loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.password.valid)" 
            color="accent">
            Login
        </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer (I know its almost a year old).  This cost me a TON of time before seeing this, and was exactly the problem I was having.  Kudos!